# Generic xaml file isn't getting added to Resources in UWP Class Library

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So I have a seemingly simple setup but for some reason my UWP app isn't processing my `Generic.xaml` file

I have a shared class library that targets 16299 and its min version is 16299.

I created a `Themes` directory and under it I put a `Generic.xaml` file which is a Resource dictionary.

Inside this I tried adding a style and then referencing it by key but the UWP app isn't able to find the style.

For example

Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemEvenRowStyle" >
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemOddRowStyle" >
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

Which results in this exception when I reference it with `StaticResource`

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The text associated with
>   this error code could not be found.
>
> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ListViewItemEvenRowStyle

I also tried putting this in `ResourceDictionary.ThemeResources` and referencing it with `ThemeResource` but I keep getting the same result.

This is the CSProj definition

```
<Page Include="Themes\Generic.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
```

Comment: did you ever figure out how to get this working?  I too am attempting to put a control in a class library, and have tried to copy the Toolkit approach referenced below, but templates never get applied.

Comment: @JerryDavis I don't believe I did. I think I had to manually add the Generic.xaml to the apps global resource dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`, instead of ResourceDictionary.ThemeResources.

In your main UWP project, open the 'App.xaml' file, add the following code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="YourClassLibrary/Themes/Generic.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

More information, please see [XAML theme resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources#theme-resources-v-static-resources) and [ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries).

***[Updated on 2019/7/10]***

> I'm curious how Infragistics, Telerik, and Microsoft UWP.Toolkit manage to accomplish this. If I add a telerik control dll to my project and reference their controls, I don't need to add anything to my resource dictionaries.

The [Telerik](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP) and [WindowsCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) are open source. You could check their source code. These controls are custom controls. Each control has its own style file and it will be applied to it in the control's constructor method by setting `DefaultStyleKey = typeof(YourCustomControlClass)`.

For example, the [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Carousel/](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Carousel) control. You could see the `Carousel.xaml` style file is in the same folder with the `Carousel.cs` class. In the `Carousel` constructor, it uses `DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Carousel);` to apply the style. But just with these steps, the system still cannot find the corresponding style. You could see the [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Themes/](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Themes) folder, it has a `Generic.xaml` file in there. It actually is a 'ResourceDictionary'. It use `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` to merge resource in different custom control folders.

With this way, the main project just need to add reference to your control library and use the controls directly without using `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` in the main project.

Comment: This tightly couples the main UWP project to the control library. I would imagine a consumer would just want to add the control lib reference to their project and start using controls without having to do this.

Comment: I'm curious how Infragistics, Telerik, and Microsoft UWP.Toolkit manage to accomplish this. If I add a telerik control dll to my project and reference their controls, I don't need to add anything to my resource dictionaries.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Finally, I understood your requirement. Please see my updated reply. In the beginning, I thought you were making a shared style file in your class library. But actually, you're making a custom controls library, you want to make these custom controls automatically use the corresponding style in the library and the consumers do not need to manually use `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` in their project.